# Replace accentuated vowels with common vowels in c++

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a string with text in spanish, and i want to replace certain characters like this:

| character | replace-with: |
| --- | --- |
| á | a |
| é | e |
| í | i |
| ó | o |
| ú | u |
| ñ | n |

I've tried this without result:

```
std::string RemoverTildes(std::string str){
    std::string sinTildes = str.c_str();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if(sinTildes[i] == 'á'){
            sinTildes[i] = 'a';
        } else if(sinTildes[i] == 'é'){
            sinTildes[i] = 'e';
        } else if(sinTildes[i] == 'í'){
            sinTildes[i] = 'i';
        } else if(sinTildes[i] == 'ó'){
            sinTildes[i] = 'o';
        } else if(sinTildes[i] == 'ú'){
            sinTildes[i] = 'u';
        } else if(sinTildes[i] == 'ñ'){
            sinTildes[i] = 'n';
        }
    }
    return sinTildes;
}
```

How can i accomplish this ? is there any library or something that i can use to do it ?

Comment: What is the character encoding?  You need a single-byte character set in order to do comparisons on individual bytes of the string, and your source code editor has to be using the same single-byte character set.  If you edit your C++ code in (for example) a UTF-8 text editor, those character literals you are comparing to won't be what you expect.  And if your input data is UTF-8, you need to look for sequences of bytes not single bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Unicode (UTF-16LE) `wchar_t` to operate with this characters. You can read more about `char` types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/char-wchar-t-char16-t-char32-t?view=msvc-160).

Here is your code with use example.

```
#include <iostream>

void tildesRemover(wchar_t* wideString) {
  auto stringLen = sizeof(wideString);
  for (int i = 0; i < stringLen; i++){
    if (wideString[i] == L'á'){
      wideString[i] = 'a';
    } else if (wideString[i] == L'é'){
      wideString[i] = 'e';
    } else if (wideString[i] == L'í'){
      wideString[i] = 'i';
    } else if (wideString[i] == L'ó'){
      wideString[i] = 'o';
    } else if (wideString[i] == L'ú'){
      wideString[i] = 'u';
    } else if (wideString[i] == L'ñ'){
      wideString[i] = 'n';
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  wchar_t wideString[] = L"áíéíúñó";

  tildesRemover(wideString);

  std::wcout << wideString << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

`L` here specifies `wchar_t`.